# tips for working on a large javascript project

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some experience with JavaScript - but mainly with some small stuff, I never did anything really big in Javascript previously.

Right now, however, I'm doing quite a large javascript-related project, a jquery-powered frontend that communicates with the server-side backend by sending/receiving JSON via Ajax.

I'm wondering if you could provide some useful information on how to deal with large javascript projects - are there any helpful tools/libaries/good practices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you minify and gzip your javascript for the client.

Comment: @grigory there is no need of any tools , write some generic helper functions and common fucntions for repeated code

Comment: and you have Stackoverflow with you

Comment: @Asaph I guess he isn't talking about the size of JS file..

Comment: @Avinash: He asked for advice on large javascript projects in an open ended way. I think my advice on minify and gzip is highly relevant to the question.

Comment: @asaph , your advice will be used at later stages during deployment and improving performance on production

Comment: answer I submitted for a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359991/how-to-develop-a-plan-for-your-javascript/4360498#4360498  Also, another link that deals with using the Module Pattern with JS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718172/using-the-module-pattern-for-larger-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grigory ,

Even i moved from a backend to UI few months back only follow this approach

1. read all the concepts of jquery
   either from google or through some
   book or through jquery
   documentation.
2. follow some of the jquery best practices   http://psdcollector.blogspot.com/2010/03/77-best-jquery-tips-i-have-ever-read.html
3. write utitlity functions for all repeated code like getcookie ,subsstrings etc etc
4. keep getting your code reviewed by experienced person who can guide you
5. post to stackoverflow if you get stuck anywhere.
6. as it is big project divide into mutiple files and use proper naming convintion.

please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: +1, use Naming conventions, namespaces, objects! Don't be tempted by old-school javascript or its tutorial - the web is full of outdated resources on JS.

Comment: @grigory , let us know whenver you need any help , i am also working on large jquery json project

Comment: and custom events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery

Answer (score 5):

My one big tip would **modularize**

In JavaScript, it is very easy for variables to clobber other variables. In order to avoid this, modularization is a must. There are several ways to take advantage of JavaScripts scope rules to minimize the possibility of variable conflicts.

```
var myProject = {};

myProject.form = function(p_name, p_method, p_action)
{
    var name = p_name,
        method = p_method,
        action = p_action;
    var addInput = function(p_input)
    {
        // etc...
    }

    return {
        addInput: addInput,
        name: name
    };
}

myProject.input = function(p_name, p_type, p_value)
{
    var name, method, value;
    var setValue = function(p_value)
    {
        value = p_value;
        return true;
    }

    return {
        setValue: setValue,
        name: name
    };
}

// etc...
```

If you're careful about using `var`, and keep track of your function scope, then you have only one global variable - `myProject`.

In order to get a new form Object, you'd simply do the following: `var myForm = myProject.form('form1', 'post', 'post.php')`.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out ***[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)***

> Backbone supplies structure to
>   JavaScript-heavy applications by
>   providing models with key-value
>   binding and custom events, collections
>   with a rich API of enumerable
>   functions, views with declarative
>   event handling, and connects it all to
>   your existing application over a
>   RESTful JSON interface.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery and YUI 3: A Tale of Two JavaScript Libraries](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/10/27/jquery-and-yui-3-a-tale-of-two-javascript-libraries/) is a nice comparison of them in the context of a complex application, and gives useful hints for jQuery programmers as well.

Comment: Why was this voted down? Seemed extremely relevant to me. Even if the poster is not going to move away from jQuery he should know what he's up against.

Comment: If you want to vote down answers to such a broad question, at least add why the answer is wrong/dangerous - even if it is not *the* right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice is to keep your code segmented in different files as "classes". I personally hate working in a file that's more than a few hundred lines long.

Then assemble and minify your code with one of the tools on the web, like [Shrinksafe](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/) or [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)

Note that Dojo, YUI, and Ext are all designed to handle large Ajax applications. You'll struggle a bit with jQuery. But I'm guessing this app isn't all **that** big and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider checking out [MooTools?](http://mootools.net/)

MooTools is a compact, modular, `Object-Oriented JavaScript framework` designed for the intermediate to advanced JavaScript developer. It allows you to write powerful, flexible, and cross-browser code with its elegant, well documented, and coherent API.